# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to run water quality prediction but got an error:

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

#### Code

This is code for `app.py`

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    # If a form is submitted
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        
        # Unpickle classifier
        clf1 = joblib.load("clfwq.pkl")
        
        # Get values through input bars
        do = request.form.get("do")
        ph = request.form.get("ph")
        orp = request.form.get("orp")
        ec = request.form.get("ec")
        tds = request.form.get("tds")
        temp = request.form.get("temp")
        cdo = request.form.get("cdo")
        cph = request.form.get("cph")
        corp = request.form.get("corp")
        cec = request.form.get("cec")
        ctds = request.form.get("ctds")
        cwt = request.form.get("cwt")
        
        # Put inputs to dataframe
        X = pd.DataFrame([[do, ph, orp, ec, tds, temp, cdo, cph, corp, cec, ctds, cwt ]], columns = ["Do", "pH", "ORP", "EC", "TDS", "Water_Temp", "CDO","CpH","CORP", "CEC", "CTDS","CWT"])
        
        # Get prediction
        prediction1 = clf1.predict(X)[0]
        
    else:
        prediction1 = ""
        
    return render_template("classify.html", output = prediction1)
```

This is the code for `model.py`

```
import joblib

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

df1 = pd.read_csv("july_wqc_edit.csv")

X1 = df1[["Do", "pH", "ORP", "EC", "TDS", "Water_Temp", "CDO", "CpH", "CORP", "CEC", "CTDS", "CWT"]]
y1 = df1["wqc"]

clf1 = GaussianNB() 
clf1.fit(X1, y1)

joblib.dump(clf1, "clfwq.pkl")
```

I already found a solution on the internet but it seems I did not manage to fix it yet.

My CSV file did not contain any `NaN` value at all.

Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the values in my numpy array that are NaN/infinity/too large for dtype('float64')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193696/how-do-i-find-the-values-in-my-numpy-array-that-are-nan-infinity-too-large-for-d)

Comment: Please share your research, i.e. the solution with a link. Did the same error came again - although CSV does not contain NaN?

Comment: Would also help to post the complete error-output including stack trace back. So we can find the location in code where the error originates from. See also [how to clean the data-frame in case of this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)